# Making Borders with background images

Tags: css

The question looks like, i am asking for a code, but that's not so. I googled plenty of times and landed in pages which did not told what i wanted. It may be my bad part to not find it in google.

I've seen it somewhere, probably on some site, that i don't recall

I have six png files, namely,

> top_right.png, 
>   top_left.png, 
>   bottom_right.png,
>   bottom_left.png, 
>   horizontal.png,
>   verical.png

What i want is to make is a box, with borders using the images above.

I think it has to do something with background position and percent, but i couldn't find how to do it?

Comment: You want to make only one border around all images? or separate border

Comment: @ling.s I want to use those images to make a border to a div content

Comment: So are you saying that you want to use these images as the borders?

Comment: @Swordfish0321 : Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate them using commas ex:

```
body {
    background-image: url(bottom.png), url(top-right.png);
    background-position: center bottom, right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: so, the background-image, and background-position has one-to-one correspondence?

Comment: As long as there is an equal amount, yes.